# Are sun synchronous orbits possible for any place on Earth?

Tags: orbit, sun-synchronous

Do sun-synchronous orbit pass **any** spot around Earth at a specified local time?
If yes or no, what is the reason?
(I know that this type of orbit passes everywhere at the equator at the same local time.)
thank you so much.

Comment: What do you mean "at a specified local time"? Certainly there's not much freedom of *when* such an orbit would pass given point. especially  depending on what you define "a point"; the satellite is small, Earth is big.

Comment: Hint: inclination limits the maximum latitude.

Comment: This question needs _a lot_ of editing. At a _specified local time_, _any_ orbit is passing above _some_ particular point on Earth, so yes. Are you asking if the orbit passes over a specific location on Earth at the _same_ local time every day?

Comment: I know that every satellite in sun-synchronous orbit passes the equator at a specified local time. for example, each point in equator where the satellite(in sun-synchronus orbit) is above it will be at 12:00(am/pm) o'clock. my question is: what about other latitudes? Do they at 12:00 o'clock? Are their local time specified?

Answer (score 12):

Sun-synchronous orbits take advantage of the *precession* of the ascending node due to orbit perturbations (primarily the $J_2$ spherical harmonic due to the slight bulge in Earth's shape at the equator). By choosing the right combination of orbit altitude and inclination, that precession can be set to take 1 year so that the local time remains the same at each location *in the orbit*. The required inclination is typically quite high, resulting in a polar orbit.

That orbit is not synchronized with the Earth's *rotation*, so the satellite does not pass over the same longitude each time it crosses the equator. See the last figure on [this NASA page](http://earthobservatory.nasa.gov/Features/OrbitsCatalog/page2.php):

[image]

Remember that *local time* is... well... local! There is continuously a spot (an entire arc, in fact) sweeping across the Earth where it is noon -- the best time to take photographs with the Sun at your back, which is usually why you use a sun-synchronous orbit in the first place.

So, are sun-synchronous orbits possible for any place on Earth? Well, there is nothing really special about sun-synchronous orbits when it comes to coverage in terms of location (just the timing). For an orbit to pass over a particular location on Earth, you just need to have the right orbit inclination for that location's latitude (Deer Hunter hinted at this). How often you pass over the location depends on the orbit period, and it *is* possible to have orbits that are in some resonance with Earth's rotation (hence they only pass over particular regions repeatedly... like geo-synchronous orbits) -- but let's ignore that since most orbits will eventually cover all longitudes. Sun-synchronous orbits are high-inclination, and the tilt of the Earth's rotation axis means that the orbit will eventually cover all latitudes as well. So sun-synchronous orbits can cover *any* point on Earth.

In short, **yes, sun-synchronous orbits are possible for any location on Earth**.

Comment: The polar regions won't be missed as they will pass under the sun-synchronous orbit twice a year. Of course this being a brief period with the relatively "sparse" orbit it may take good several years for the satellite to appear over a specific spot of that region.

Comment: Oh yes of course, thank you, answer edited accordingly!

Comment: @SF. - Your comment is incorrect. Sun synchronous satellites never pass directly over the poles. The A-train satellites, for example, have an orbital inclination of 98.2 degrees, and hence never go north of 81.8 degrees north latitude. The poles are in view from the northernmost point of the orbit, but are never directly below.

Comment: @DavidHammen: Is that true for sun-synchronous satellites that "ride the terminator line"? If so, how does the pole pass 23.4 degrees to the day/night side without ever passing below these satellites?

Comment: @SF. -- It's true for all sun synchronous satellites. A truly polar orbit would not precess due to the Earth's oblateness and thus cannot be sun synchronous. Those sun-synchronous satellites that "ride the terminator" don't actually ride the terminator. They come close. Example: http://www.heavens-above.com/orbit.aspx?satid=23710

Comment: @DavidHammen: If they are closer to terminator than 23 degrees, they WILL pass over the pole. Pole travels 23 degrees one or the other way of terminator, there's no way it can't cross the orbit.

Comment: @SF. - They cannot pass over the poles. The northernmost subsatellite point of a sun synchronous satellite is about 80 to 82 degrees. Please read https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/8194/why-does-the-sun-synchronous-orbital-plane-rotate , which discusses the math behind sun synchronous orbits.

Comment: @David: 80 to 82 degrees relative to Earth equator or Celestial equator?

Comment: @SF -- The Celestial equatorial plane and the Earth's equatorial plane are more or less the same thing. You are perhaps thinking of the ecliptic plane. And yes, it's with respect to the Earth's equatorial plane. Sun synchronous satellites cannot pass directly over the poles. It's in the math.

Comment: It looks like @BrianLynch added the conclusion "in short, **yes, sun-synchronous orbits are possible for any location on Earth**." only after prompting. I've posted a separate [answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/26258/12102) indicating this is not really the case.

Answer (score 3):

For:

> Do sun-synchronous orbit pass **any** spot around Earth... (emphasis added)

Sun-synchronous orbits use the strong $J_2$ component of the Earth's gravity to precess their ascending node all the way around *the Earth's axis* once per year.

Since the Earth's axis is tipped by ~23 degrees with respect to the ecliptic, it is important to remember that this precession happens relative to the Earth's axis and equatorial bulge, and although it happens to be synchronized to the Earth's orbit around the Sun in a 1:1 ratio, it does not have anything specifically to do with the Sun.

Rather, the orbital plane slowly rotates around the Earth's North-South axis once per 365+ days. Think of a piece of paper pierced by a pencil, and then tilted. Now think of spinning this around the pencil once a year without changing the way the paper is tilted on the pencil. It does not matter that the pencil is tilted 23 degrees relative to some light bulb 150,000,000 km away.

The equatorial bulge, and all other gravitational effects have only a very tiny effect on the orbit's inclination over time, so **for practical purposes you think of the inclination as nearly constant**, at least for decades.

That means if the inclination of the orbit were say 60 degrees, it would never pass over latitudes higher than 60 degrees. Even if it were nearly polar at say 98 degrees, it would never pass latitudes higher than 180-98 = 82 degrees.

So no, not **any** point.

---

For:

> ...pass (a) spot around Earth **at a specified local time?** (emphasis added)

I'm guessing you mean it would regularly pass over (a) spot at the same time *each day*. That would be a special case of the Sun Synchronous orbit with an *approximately repeating ground track* as discussed in this [Technical details](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sun-synchronous_orbit#Technical_details) section. For example, if the altitude of a circular orbit were 901 km and the inclination were about 99 degrees, it would orbit 14 times per day and for a spot that it did pass over, it would do it at roughly the same time each day.

See the answers to [Are there terms for Earth orbits with rational number multiples of 1 sidereal day?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/18066/12102) for more thoughts on this.