# What are the chances that the ISS transits the moon as seen from your house (or headquarters)?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, spacex, iss, the-moon, dragon

In [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/19556/12102) I tried to do a simple probablistic estimate on the distribution of the ISS's ground track passes over Earth's equator.

Recently there is a photo of the ISS passing over SpaceX headquarters, with a Dragon capsule docked to it at the time and the disk of the Moon nearly directly behind it.

Links in the question [How does the ISS Transit Finder website get the position of the ISS so accurately?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/29808/12102) show that you can get a website to tell you where and when to go so that the ISS passes between you and the moon, and that already takes some planning and waiting.

But what are the chances, let's say per year, roughly, that such a transit would be viewable from SpaceX headquarters rather just some location within a 100 km radius of it, and while there was a SpaceX spacecraft docket to it at the same time?

> [spacex](https://www.instagram.com/spacex/) Dragon and the @ISS passed over SpaceX headquarters and across the face of the Moon last weekend. After a month-long stay, Dragon will detach from the orbiting laboratory and return to Earth on August 3.

https://www.instagram.com/p/Bl8xjJFFrHM/

[image: ISS lunar transit Spacex] [image: ISS lunar transit Spacex]

"Bonus points" if someone can figure out *when* exactly this happened.

Comment: [A related conjunction](https://youtu.be/lepQoU4oek4)- They give a brief explanation of finding the viewing location, but it’s mostly just a really cool video!

Comment: @Jack I like that even better, and hadn't seen this episode before, thanks! btw any idea what that funky shimmering pattern on the sheet hanging vertically at `04:30` was?  *update:* I've just asked [What is causing this strange shimmering pattern of light during a total solar eclipse?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/27221/7982)