# How can I find orbital parameters for a sun-synchronous orbit?

Tags: ephemeris, sun-synchronous

I would like to compute ephemerides for a satellite on a sun-synchronous orbit, starting with only the following parameters<sup>1</sup>:

- altitude or inclination;
- local time of the ascending or descending node;
- starting date.

Using Orekit, I am able to compute ephemerides for a circular orbit given: the orbit radius, the inclination, the right-ascending node, the true anomaly, and the starting date.

I already know how to link altitude and inclination, and computing the orbit radius from these is trivial, but I do not know how to find the RAAN and the true anomaly given the above parameters.

I found this related question [How Local time of a sun synchronous orbit is related to Right ascension of ascending node?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/22125/how-local-time-of-a-sun-synchronous-orbit-is-related-to-right-ascension-of-ascen), but there the answers do not provide formula to compute the required parameters.

Is there a way to compute the RAAN and true anomaly from the above parameters? Or another way to compute ephemerides starting only with the above parameters?

<sub><sup>1</sup> I am assuming this is possible since it is how a sun-synchronous orbit is specified in STK.</sub>

Comment: What exactly does a sun-synchronous orbit mean?  The Sun does rotates non-rigidly, and so is presents a range of rotation periods to the outside observer.

Comment: @Oscar Lanzi  I refer you to https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/8194/why-does-the-sun-synchronous-orbital-plane-rotate?